# Accord du pluriel "x sur y"

Tags: accord, pluriel

Faut-il écrire (il s'agit d'une erreur provenant d'un logiciel) :

> 0 sur 100 conversation récupérée

ou :

> 0 sur 100 conversations récupérées

Comment: Dans tous les cas, le deuxième phrase devrait être "*conversations récupérées*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je dirais :

> 0 conversation récupérée sur 100 (traitées).

Si la formulation initiale ne peut pas être changée, j'accorderais avec le nombre de conversation récupérée, soit 0 :

> 0 sur 100 conversation récupérée

Comment: la forme initiale ne doit pas être changée malheureusement :(

Answer (score 1):

En considérant que *0 sur cent* est une variation de *0 pour cent*, on devrait pouvoir aussi écrire :

> 0 sur 100 conversations **récupérées**

comme on dit couramment :

> 0 % des conversations [ont été] récupérées

ou

> Il y en a zéro qui sont **récupérées**. (plutôt que : *il y en a zéro qui est récupérée*)

On peut aussi tenter le plus risqué mais conforme à l'accord au singulier de zéro :

> 0 sur 100 conversations **récupéré**.

puisqu'on peut très bien dire :

> *0 % des conversations [a été] récupéré*.

Conversations devrait rester au pluriel puisqu'il y en a cent.

Comment: 100 est un exemple malheureux je pense. il pourait très bien y avoir 126 conversations à récupérer. Perso je garderais tout au pluriel, il y a beaucoup moins de cas où cela sera erroné.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, le pluriel est plus naturel. Je trouve que *zéro* devrait parfois pouvoir être accepté comme un pluriel: *Deux sont récupérées* : ok , *Une est récupérée* : ok, *Aucune n'est récupérée* : ok, mais *Zéro sont récupérées* me choque moins que *Zéro est récupérée*.